# PhpStorm + vue.js format

Tags: vue.js, formatting, phpstorm, webstorm

I recognized that the `Reformat Code` Key-Combination (`⌥⇧⌘L`) won´t perform any action in `.vue` files anymore (PhpStorm 2020.2).

In the bottom action / task bar the action is started but nothing changed:

[image: taskbar-action started]

When I go right-click on the file and select `Reformat Code`, the code is formatted as configured.

When I delete the `.idea` folder and restart, it works - but after next restart the key combination is broken, again.

I also disabled almost all plugins, but still the same behaviour. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: does it only happen with `.vue` files? Did you try assigning a different shortcut to **Reformat Code** action in **Preferences | Keymap**?

Comment: @lena yes, only in ```.vue``` files. I recognize that the Reformat Action is called in the Action Toolbar in the bottom right. But it doesn´t change in the editor.

Comment: I added a Screenshot, that appears when i hit the Key-Combination

Comment: is **Optimize imports** option enabled in the **Reformat File** dialog (if you open it with your `.vue` file selected)?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Comment: does disabling it help?

Comment: Yes, when disabling *Optimize imports* the format via shortcut works!

Comment: Must be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-46732, please follow it for updates